# How to solve Ignite client startup blocking caused by Affinity for topology version is not initialized?

Tags: ignite, gridgain

When I am using the Ignite standard client to connect to the cluster, it seems that the client is blocking in the startup phase and will not continue executing.

Check the server log and see the following error message:

```
(err) Failed to notify listener (is grid stopped?) [fut=GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture [firstDiscoEvt=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=cc6c7f4c-2614-40c5-8c7d-158da202f203, consistentId=cc6c7f4c-2614-40c5-8c7d-158da202f203, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.221.42, 240e:604:20b:fd81:0:0:0:348], sockAddrs=HashSet [/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:0, /127.0.0.1:0, LAPTOP-KPI69JA3/192.168.221.42:0, /240e:604:20b:fd81:0:0:0:348:0], discPort=0, order=5, intOrder=4, lastExchangeTime=1681436112330, loc=false, ver=8.8.9#20210928-sha1:3d3f078a, isClient=true], topVer=5, msgTemplate=Node joined: , nodeId8=39af77f4, msg=Node joined: TcpDiscoveryNode [id=cc6c7f4c-2614-40c5-8c7d-158da202f203, consistentId=cc6c7f4c-2614-40c5-8c7d-158da202f203, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.221.42, 240e:604:20b:fd81:0:0:0:348], sockAddrs=HashSet [/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:0, /127.0.0.1:0, LAPTOP-KPI69JA3/192.168.221.42:0, /240e:604:20b:fd81:0:0:0:348:0], discPort=0, order=5, intOrder=4, lastExchangeTime=1681436112330, loc=false, ver=8.8.9#20210928-sha1:3d3f078a, isClient=true], type=NODE_JOINED, tstamp=1681436112346], crd=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=39af77f4-fdca-49b8-829f-51c52a15d450, consistentId=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1,127.0.0.1,192.168.221.42,240e:604:20b:fd81:0:0:0:348:47500, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.221.42, 240e:604:20b:fd81:0:0:0:348], sockAddrs=HashSet [/240e:604:20b:fd81:0:0:0:348:47500, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500, LAPTOP-KPI69JA3/192.168.221.42:47500], discPort=47500, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1681436112346, loc=true, ver=8.8.9#20230414-sha1:00000000, isClient=false], exchId=GridDhtPartitionExchangeId [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=5, minorTopVer=0], discoEvt=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=cc6c7f4c-2614-40c5-8c7d-158da202f203, consistentId=cc6c7f4c-2614-40c5-8c7d-158da202f203, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.221.42, 240e:604:20b:fd81:0:0:0:348], sockAddrs=HashSet [/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:0, /127.0.0.1:0, LAPTOP-KPI69JA3/192.168.221.42:0, /240e:604:20b:fd81:0:0:0:348:0], discPort=0, order=5, intOrder=4, lastExchangeTime=1681436112330, loc=false, ver=8.8.9#20210928-sha1:3d3f078a, isClient=true], topVer=5, msgTemplate=Node joined: , nodeId8=39af77f4, msg=Node joined: TcpDiscoveryNode [id=cc6c7f4c-2614-40c5-8c7d-158da202f203, consistentId=cc6c7f4c-2614-40c5-8c7d-158da202f203, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.221.42, 240e:604:20b:fd81:0:0:0:348], sockAddrs=HashSet [/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:0, /127.0.0.1:0, LAPTOP-KPI69JA3/192.168.221.42:0, /240e:604:20b:fd81:0:0:0:348:0], discPort=0, order=5, intOrder=4, lastExchangeTime=1681436112330, loc=false, ver=8.8.9#20210928-sha1:3d3f078a, isClient=true], type=NODE_JOINED, tstamp=1681436112346], nodeId=cc6c7f4c, evt=NODE_JOINED], added=true, exchangeType=NONE, initFut=GridFutureAdapter [ignoreInterrupts=false, state=DONE, hash=1571612962], init=false, lastVer=null, partReleaseFut=null, exchActions=null, affChangeMsg=null, centralizedAff=false, forceAffReassignment=false, exchangeLocE=null, cacheChangeFailureMsgSent=false, done=true, state=DONE, registerCachesFuture=GridFinishedFuture [resFlag=2], startTime=1681436112353, initTime=1681436112353, rebalanced=true, affinityReassign=false, evtLatch=0, remaining=HashSet [], mergedJoinExchMsgs=null, awaitMergedMsgs=0, super=GridFutureAdapter [ignoreInterrupts=false, state=DONE, hash=862544934]], lsnr=o.a.i.i.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture$3@5e2b1fea, err=Affinity for topology version is not initialized [locNode=39af77f4-fdca-49b8-829f-51c52a15d450, grp=PRODUCT2, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=5, minorTopVer=0], head=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=5, minorTopVer=2], history=[AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=5, minorTopVer=2]]]]java.lang.IllegalStateException: Affinity for topology version is not initialized [locNode=39af77f4-fdca-49b8-829f-51c52a15d450, grp=PRODUCT2, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=5, minorTopVer=0], head=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=5, minorTopVer=2], history=[AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=5, minorTopVer=2]]]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.affinity.GridAffinityAssignmentCache.readyAffinity(GridAffinityAssignmentCache.java:746)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.affinity.GridAffinityAssignmentCache.readyAssignments(GridAffinityAssignmentCache.java:614)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.CacheGroupAffinityMessage.lambda$createAffinityMessages$0(CacheGroupAffinityMessage.java:168)
    at java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1126)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.CacheGroupAffinityMessage.createAffinityMessages(CacheGroupAffinityMessage.java:153)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.sendAllPartitionsToNode(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:4423)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.access$800(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:160)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture$3.apply(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:3187)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture$3.apply(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:3146)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.notifyListener(GridFutureAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.listen(GridFutureAdapter.java:362)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.waitAndReplyToNode(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:3146)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.processSingleMessage(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:3201)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.fastReplyOnSingleMessage(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:3131)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$2.onMessage(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:431)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$2.onMessage(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:414)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$MessageHandler.apply(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:3822)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$MessageHandler.apply(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:3801)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.processMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:1150)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.onMessage0(GridCacheIoManager.java:591)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.handleMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:392)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.handleMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:318)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.access$100(GridCacheIoManager.java:109)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager$1.onMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:308)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1725)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:1332)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$4800(GridIoManager.java:157)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$8.execute(GridIoManager.java:1217)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.TraceRunnable.run(TraceRunnable.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Looking at the client log, it seems to be blocked here:

```
[09:35:10]    __________  ________________ 
[09:35:10]   /  _/ ___/ |/ /  _/_  __/ __/ 
[09:35:10]  _/ // (7 7    // /  / / / _/   
[09:35:10] /___/\___/_/|_/___/ /_/ /___/  
[09:35:10] 
[09:35:10] ver. 8.8.9#20210928-sha1:3d3f078a
[09:35:10] 2021 Copyright(C) GridGain Systems, Inc. and Contributors
[09:35:10] 
[09:35:10] Ignite documentation: http://gridgain.com
[09:35:10] 
[09:35:10] Quiet mode.
[09:35:10]   ^-- Logging to file '.\ignite\work\log\ignite-cc6c7f4c.log'
[09:35:10]   ^-- Logging by 'Log4J2Logger [quiet=true, config=file:/D:/maven/apache-maven-3.6.0-bin/apache-maven-3.6.0/repository/org/gridgain/ignite-core/8.8.9/ignite-core-8.8.9.jar!/META-INF/ignite-log4j2.xml]'
[09:35:10]   ^-- To see **FULL** console log here add -DIGNITE_QUIET=false or "-v" to ignite.{sh|bat}
[09:35:10] 
[09:35:10] OS: Windows 10 10.0 amd64
[09:35:10] VM information: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_144-b01 Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.144-b01
[09:35:10] Please set system property '-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true' to avoid possible problems in mixed environments.
[09:35:10] Configured plugins:
[09:35:10]   ^-- None
[09:35:10] 
[09:35:10] Configured failure handler: [hnd=StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler [tryStop=false, timeout=0, super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=UnmodifiableSet [SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, SYSTEM_CRITICAL_OPERATION_TIMEOUT]]]]
[09:35:10] Initial heap size is 222MB (should be no less than 512MB, use -Xms512m -Xmx512m).
[09:35:10] Message queue limit is set to 0 which may lead to potential OOMEs when running cache operations in FULL_ASYNC or PRIMARY_SYNC modes due to message queues growth on sender and receiver sides.
[09:35:11] Security status [authentication=off, tls/ssl=off]
[09:35:11] REST protocols do not start on client node. To start the protocols on client node set '-DIGNITE_REST_START_ON_CLIENT=true' system property.
[09:35:12] Nodes started on local machine require more than 80% of physical RAM what can lead to significant slowdown due to swapping (please decrease JVM heap size, data region size or checkpoint buffer size) [required=12413MB, available=14204MB]
[09:35:22] New version is available at gridgain.com: 8.8.27
```

Client detailed logs:

```
[2023-04-14T09:35:22,546][WARN ][exchange-worker-#77][diagnostic] Failed to wait for partition map exchange [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=5, minorTopVer=0], node=cc6c7f4c-2614-40c5-8c7d-158da202f203]. Consider changing TransactionConfiguration.txTimeoutOnPartitionMapExchange to non default value to avoid this message. Dumping pending objects that might be the cause: 
[2023-04-14T09:35:22,546][WARN ][exchange-worker-#77][diagnostic] Ready affinity version: AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=-1, minorTopVer=0]
[2023-04-14T09:35:22,550][WARN ][exchange-worker-#77][diagnostic] Last exchange future: GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture [firstDiscoEvt=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=cc6c7f4c-2614-40c5-8c7d-158da202f203, consistentId=cc6c7f4c-2614-40c5-8c7d-158da202f203, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.221.42, 240e:604:20b:fd81:0:0:0:348], sockAddrs=HashSet [/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:0, /127.0.0.1:0, LAPTOP-KPI69JA3/192.168.221.42:0, /240e:604:20b:fd81:0:0:0:348:0], discPort=0, order=5, intOrder=0, lastExchangeTime=1681436112314, loc=true, ver=8.8.9#20210928-sha1:3d3f078a, isClient=true], topVer=5, msgTemplate=null, nodeId8=cc6c7f4c, msg=null, type=NODE_JOINED, tstamp=1681436112394], crd=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=39af77f4-fdca-49b8-829f-51c52a15d450, consistentId=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1,127.0.0.1,192.168.221.42,240e:604:20b:fd81:0:0:0:348:47500, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.221.42, 240e:604:20b:fd81:0:0:0:348], sockAddrs=HashSet [/240e:604:20b:fd81:0:0:0:348:47500, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500, LAPTOP-KPI69JA3/192.168.221.42:47500], discPort=47500, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1681436112346, loc=false, ver=8.8.9#20230414-sha1:00000000, isClient=false], exchId=GridDhtPartitionExchangeId [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=5, minorTopVer=0], discoEvt=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=cc6c7f4c-2614-40c5-8c7d-158da202f203, consistentId=cc6c7f4c-2614-40c5-8c7d-158da202f203, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.221.42, 240e:604:20b:fd81:0:0:0:348], sockAddrs=HashSet [/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:0, /127.0.0.1:0, LAPTOP-KPI69JA3/192.168.221.42:0, /240e:604:20b:fd81:0:0:0:348:0], discPort=0, order=5, intOrder=0, lastExchangeTime=1681436112314, loc=true, ver=8.8.9#20210928-sha1:3d3f078a, isClient=true], topVer=5, msgTemplate=null, nodeId8=cc6c7f4c, msg=null, type=NODE_JOINED, tstamp=1681436112394], nodeId=cc6c7f4c, evt=NODE_JOINED], added=true, exchangeType=CLIENT, initFut=GridFutureAdapter [ignoreInterrupts=false, state=DONE, hash=1036099390], init=true, lastVer=null, partReleaseFut=null, exchActions=ExchangeActions [startCaches=null, stopCaches=null, startGrps=[], stopGrps=[], resetParts=null, stateChangeRequest=null], affChangeMsg=null, centralizedAff=false, forceAffReassignment=false, exchangeLocE=null, cacheChangeFailureMsgSent=false, done=false, state=CLIENT, registerCachesFuture=GridFinishedFuture [resFlag=2], startTime=1681436112405, initTime=1681436112458, rebalanced=false, affinityReassign=false, evtLatch=0, remaining=HashSet [39af77f4-fdca-49b8-829f-51c52a15d450], mergedJoinExchMsgs=null, awaitMergedMsgs=0, super=GridFutureAdapter [ignoreInterrupts=false, state=INIT, res=null, hash=1238405376]]
[2023-04-14T09:35:22,550][WARN ][exchange-worker-#77][GridCachePartitionExchangeManager] First 10 pending exchange futures [total=2]
[2023-04-14T09:35:22,551][WARN ][exchange-worker-#77][GridCachePartitionExchangeManager] >>> GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=5, minorTopVer=1], evt=DISCOVERY_CUSTOM_EVT, evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=d2d2a902-7882-4882-a6af-9a3053a612be, consistentId=d2d2a902-7882-4882-a6af-9a3053a612be, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.221.42, 240e:604:20b:fd81:0:0:0:348], sockAddrs=HashSet [/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:0, /127.0.0.1:0, LAPTOP-KPI69JA3/192.168.221.42:0, /240e:604:20b:fd81:0:0:0:348:0], discPort=0, order=4, intOrder=3, lastExchangeTime=1681436112346, loc=false, ver=8.8.9#20210928-sha1:3d3f078a, isClient=true], rebalanced=false, done=false, newCrdFut=null]
[2023-04-14T09:35:22,551][WARN ][exchange-worker-#77][GridCachePartitionExchangeManager] >>> GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=5, minorTopVer=2], evt=DISCOVERY_CUSTOM_EVT, evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=d2d2a902-7882-4882-a6af-9a3053a612be, consistentId=d2d2a902-7882-4882-a6af-9a3053a612be, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.221.42, 240e:604:20b:fd81:0:0:0:348], sockAddrs=HashSet [/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:0, /127.0.0.1:0, LAPTOP-KPI69JA3/192.168.221.42:0, /240e:604:20b:fd81:0:0:0:348:0], discPort=0, order=4, intOrder=3, lastExchangeTime=1681436112346, loc=false, ver=8.8.9#20210928-sha1:3d3f078a, isClient=true], rebalanced=false, done=false, newCrdFut=null]
[2023-04-14T09:35:22,552][WARN ][exchange-worker-#77][diagnostic] Last 10 exchange futures (total: 3):
[2023-04-14T09:35:22,552][WARN ][exchange-worker-#77][diagnostic] >>> GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=5, minorTopVer=2], evt=DISCOVERY_CUSTOM_EVT, evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=d2d2a902-7882-4882-a6af-9a3053a612be, consistentId=d2d2a902-7882-4882-a6af-9a3053a612be, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.221.42, 240e:604:20b:fd81:0:0:0:348], sockAddrs=HashSet [/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:0, /127.0.0.1:0, LAPTOP-KPI69JA3/192.168.221.42:0, /240e:604:20b:fd81:0:0:0:348:0], discPort=0, order=4, intOrder=3, lastExchangeTime=1681436112346, loc=false, ver=8.8.9#20210928-sha1:3d3f078a, isClient=true], rebalanced=false, done=false, newCrdFut=null]
[2023-04-14T09:35:22,552][WARN ][exchange-worker-#77][diagnostic] >>> GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=5, minorTopVer=1], evt=DISCOVERY_CUSTOM_EVT, evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=d2d2a902-7882-4882-a6af-9a3053a612be, consistentId=d2d2a902-7882-4882-a6af-9a3053a612be, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.221.42, 240e:604:20b:fd81:0:0:0:348], sockAddrs=HashSet [/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:0, /127.0.0.1:0, LAPTOP-KPI69JA3/192.168.221.42:0, /240e:604:20b:fd81:0:0:0:348:0], discPort=0, order=4, intOrder=3, lastExchangeTime=1681436112346, loc=false, ver=8.8.9#20210928-sha1:3d3f078a, isClient=true], rebalanced=false, done=false, newCrdFut=null]
[2023-04-14T09:35:22,553][WARN ][exchange-worker-#77][diagnostic] >>> GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=5, minorTopVer=0], evt=NODE_JOINED, evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=cc6c7f4c-2614-40c5-8c7d-158da202f203, consistentId=cc6c7f4c-2614-40c5-8c7d-158da202f203, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.221.42, 240e:604:20b:fd81:0:0:0:348], sockAddrs=HashSet [/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:0, /127.0.0.1:0, LAPTOP-KPI69JA3/192.168.221.42:0, /240e:604:20b:fd81:0:0:0:348:0], discPort=0, order=5, intOrder=0, lastExchangeTime=1681436112314, loc=true, ver=8.8.9#20210928-sha1:3d3f078a, isClient=true], rebalanced=false, done=false, newCrdFut=null]
[2023-04-14T09:35:22,553][WARN ][exchange-worker-#77][diagnostic] Latch manager state: ExchangeLatchManager [serverLatches=ConcurrentHashMap {}, clientLatches=ConcurrentHashMap {}]
[2023-04-14T09:35:22,567][INFO ][sys-#54][diagnostic] Exchange future waiting for coordinator response [crd=39af77f4-fdca-49b8-829f-51c52a15d450, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=5, minorTopVer=0]]
```

Version:

I am using Gridgain Community Edition version 8.8.9

After analysis, I believe that the reason for this situation is that the standard client in another program quickly destroyed and recreated a cache. Due to the server not handling this error correctly, the client could never receive feedback and blocked during startup.

Are there any good solutions?